# Why do some users have HTTP response codes in their display names?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts, users

I know I could ask this in [the 2nd monitor](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor) but figure this might be better here for posterity... and [this site is for questions](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/46871300#46871300)...

I noticed a while back that there are a couple users who have HTTP Response codes as their display names - namely [*200_success*](https://stackexchange.com/users/486869/200-success?tab=accounts) and [*202_accepted*](https://stackexchange.com/users/3124707/202-accepted?tab=accounts). Bearing in mind that those users have other Stack Exchange accounts, they appear to have highest reputation levels on CR and one was formerly a moderator on CR.

- Do these users have an affiliation with each other?
- Were these names chosen as part of a scheme?
- Should we know anything else about such display name formats? (e.g. are they regarded as sacred or anything?)

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/8595?m=39935214#39935214

Comment: For the record: 200_success is not a real HTTP Status Code. If it would have been correct, it would be 200_ok.

Comment: Yes it seems [2xx is the class of Success codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#2xx_Success)... and 200 is OK... hehe I also found this silly site: https://httpstatusdogs.com/200-ok

Answer (score 10):

200_success is the [username that I had picked on slashdot.org](https://slashdot.org/~200_success), back when that was my primary way to alleviate boredom at work.  At the time, I was doing more web development, and it felt good when the code worked and didn't crash and produce some 500 error.  The username was a kind of a nerdy way to express that satisfaction.

Answer (score 9):

There's no secret behind mine, as [Peilonrayz](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/users/42401/peilonrayz) [mentioned](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8996/73844):

[I stole the idea from 200_success](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/8595?m=39896197#39896197), [and brag about it regularly](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/8595?m=39935214#39935214) [to confuse *someone, somewhere* eventually (Sorry Simon)](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/8595?m=44105555#44105555). It actually came about [shortly after this article](https://www.bbc.com/news/blogs-trending-40494909) because I was just barely concerned about the visibility of it, but that's no longer an issue. (It's also a psychological trick to convince people to over-abundantly accept my answers. Muahahaha. (I kid, I kid.))

There's no secret to my *real* name, either, I [plaster](https://twitter.com/EBrown8534) it [everywhere](https://github.com/EBrown8534), I make no qualms of it. If you want info on me, feel free to look it up. :)

No, we're not socks or associated, if that's your concern. 200 has been here for just about ever (and was previously a mod), and I've been around for a while as well (joined 2 or 3 years in). It just so happens that I stole 200's idea (and thunder) and have used it to cause pain-and-suffering in the universe. :)

1. **Do these users have an affiliation with each other?** Nope. I speak with 200 in chat regularly, but that's it. (200 is from Canada, I'm from Toledo, OH, USA.)
2. **Were these names chosen as part of a scheme?** Mine was for sure, can't speak to 200's.
3. **Should we know anything else about such display name formats? (e.g. are they regarded as sacred or anything?)** Mostly just a play on HTTP. For a moment I was `418_Teapot` (because [HTTP 418 indicates the server is, in fact, a teapot](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/418)). So, no. Nothing sacred, nothing important, just fun. :)

Comment: You could opt for [**497** *Not a Chicken*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/304392/341145)

Comment: I think [Quill](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/62429/quill) went by 418 for a while.

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ I also debated [406](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39935256#39935256).

Answer (score 4):

- They are affiliated in that they both contribute to Code Review.
- Kinda, [202_accepted took insperation from 200](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/8595?m=39896197#39896197)

  > @200_success I'm stealing your display name style.
- You can add the sacred emotional attachment to them, but I guess they just chose them cause they're pretty cool. And potentially increase privacy.